# Howto make JButton with simple flat style?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

whats the most simple way to make a JButton only show the background color? I don't need any other effects like borders, 3D-look or hover-highlighting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for answering. There is still a highlighting going on, when I click the button. The rest is ok. Any idea howto stop it ftom highlighting?

Comment: You can probably control that by setting a custom `ButtonUI`.

Answer (score 33):

I usually do something like this:

```
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setFocusPainted(false);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Comment: setContentAreaFilled(false) was the last thing I was missing to make the button truly flat without a border--thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Just set the colours and the border:

```
private static JButton createSimpleButton(String text) {
  JButton button = new JButton(text);
  button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
  button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  Border line = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK);
  Border margin = new EmptyBorder(5, 15, 5, 15);
  Border compound = new CompoundBorder(line, margin);
  button.setBorder(compound);
  return button;
}
```

Use [`setOpaque(false);`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque(boolean)) to make the background transparent.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
yourButton.setBorder(null);
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a JLabel with a MouseListener instead... unless you're tied to using a JButton or ActionListener in some way.

Comment: That'll work, but has implications for keyboard focus/accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

First, set your look and feel to something cool, like 'metal'.

```
try
{
    for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo lnf : 
        UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Metal".equals(lnf.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnf.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) { /* Lazy handling this >.> */ }
```

Then do something like this:

```
my_jbutton.setBackground(new Color(240,240,241);
```

If the color of your button is exactly equals to swing control color (240,240,240), windows will apply windows-like button style to the button, otherwise, the button assumes a simple flat style.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it like this

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click Me!!");
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setBackground(new Color());// inside the brackets your rgb color value like 255,255,255
button.setFocusPainted(false);
```

you can use the color picker to get rgb code(just search color picker)