# Drawing border around JLabel when selected, like the Buttons

Tags: java, swing

I was trying to paint border around `JLabel` when it is clicked. Just like `JButtons` are painted.

I thought it would be easy but I failed to do the job.

I tried to figure out what happens to `JButtons` when clicked by putting breakpoints in source codes. But I got lost, however, I have a feeling that `javax.swing.plaf` and its subpackages are what I need.

Am I right? Is there a simpler way to do the job.

Here is an example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `MouseListener` to your label and setup a border in mousePressed/mouseReleased methods. Here is a simplified example:

```
    label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            label.setBorder(null);
        }
    });
```

Also, as an alternative you can make a button with a flat style that will look like a label. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1839173/1048330) can be useful.