# How to create the windows 8 FLAT native look in Java Swing programming?

Tags: java, swing, windows-8

I am creating a java swing application and I am badly need to get the flat GUI look like in windows 8 to my swing application. But I couldn't find it yet. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: How does a flat GUI look like in Windows 8?

Comment: That's the metro ui or modern ui or what the MS guys are calling it today. You can't write a Metro App with Java.

Comment: Metro (still) isn't accesible from Java/JavaFX,

Comment: Try with this [Stack Question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14445403/1093390

Comment: Maybe look at the *Synthetica* commercial library that makes it easy to create skins for Swing.  I have no connection to them and have never used their product, but that's all I come up with.

Comment: I do not want to create a metro app, but I need to create flat GUI like windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can PROBABLY use the default look and feel of swing apps, undecorate everything, and for those icons; I would use buttons with internal panels, images, labels, etc. To get the scroll functionality you should use mouse listeners to detect scrolling and slide the ui accordingly.